# angular dom updates Vrs React dom updates

Tags: angular, reactjs

Ok i've seen so many people try answer this but still can't brake it down into a simple answer. I understand React and how for example a property style change only updates the attribute value on the browser dom based on the difference between current virtual-dom and previous virtual-dom.

**Take Away:**
So the browser dom element does not get dumbed and recreated but instead just the value or the attribute of the element changes. makes for smart and fast render.

This has been the argument among developers that react render is better performance than Angular.

But doesn't angular do something similar without Virtual Dom, instead using zone.js and change detection. So the directive ng-class only updates the class attribute value on the Browser Dom and not full redraw of the dom element or any other dom elements in the browsers dom tree for that matter.

```
<ANY class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </ANY>
```

**Take Away:**
If this is the case then isn't that the same as React in that it only updates the specific dom change or changes and not the redraw of the dom itself or all dom elements for that matter?

So the argument that react v-dom render is faster or more efficient than angular's seem ridiculous and unfounded then ?